# What chemical compound is shown in episode 17 of Monogatari Second Season?

Tags: monogatari-series

In episode **17** of **Monogatari Second Season** (the first episode of **Onimonogatari**), when Koyomi and Mayoi see the strange "darkness", an image of the structure of a chemical compound is displayed, repeatedly:

[image: a structural formula]

Shortly afterwards, a number of different chemical compounds are displayed (numbers not present in original):

[image: lots of structural formulae (numbering added)]

What are these compounds?

Answer (score 13):

The first image is the structural formula of [**epinephrine**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epinephrine) (or **adrenaline**, depending on where you live).

[image: structural formula of epinephrine]

Epinephrine is a neurotransmitter that plays a significant role in the fight-or-flight response, and so its appearance here makes sense - Koyomi is certainly about to take flight upon seeing the "darkness".

---

The second image contains the following compounds:

1. [dopamine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dopamine)
2. [serotonin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serotonin)
3. [α-Neoendorphin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-Neoendorphin)
4. epinephrine (again)
5. [(Leu-)enkephalin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enkephalin)
6. [norepinephrine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norepinephrine) (or noradrenaline)

All of these are neurotransmitters, as well, though none of them are as localized to the fight-or-flight response as epinephrine is.